# Как отобразить сайт в зависимости от прав пользователя?

Tags: wordpress

Сверху сайта присутствует панель на которой есть ссылки на форму входа и регистрации, как сделать так, что бы там отображалось что-то на подобии "Добро пожаловать "User"" в случаее если пользователь уже вошел в систему, а для админа - "Перейти в админ панель", админка отключена для всех кроме администраторов!
Код этих ссылок:

```
<div class="login">
    <a href="<?php echo wp_login_url( $redirect ); ?>">Вход</a>
    <span>/</span>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('/wp-login.php?action=register'); ?>">Регистрация</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Использовать функцию `current_user_can()`

Например

```
<?php if( current_user_can('manage_options') ): ?>
  <a href="/wp-admin">Перейти в админ панель</a>
<?php elseif( current_user_can('read') ): ?>
  <a href="/">Добро пожаловать "User"</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

Более детально об этом можно прочитать [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/current_user_can)

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Буду пробовать реализовать... А как написать условие отображения для гостя?

Comment: Проверить на `is_user_logged_in()`. Если пользователь залогинен, то функция вернёт `true`, и в обратном случае `false`

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо ещё раз, буду пробовать...